# Set geodesic convexity on positive curvature manifolds under linear transformation

Tags: convex-analysis, riemannian-geometry, curvature, geodesic

Let M be a Riemannian manifold in $\mathbb{R}^n$ of positive sectional curvature and S be a geodesically convex set on M and $T \in GL(n, \mathbb{R})$. Is it true that $T(S)$ is geodesically convex in $T(M)$? If not would it be true in special case of $M$ being hyperellipsoid?

Without curvature positivity you can cook up a counter-example to this statement: $M$ is flat everywhere except for a low ridge, $S$ covers that ridge. A geodesic in $S$ runs over this low ridge and remains in $S$. $T$ stretches the ridge upwards a lot and geodesic is forced to go around leaving $S$.

I also tried analyzing $||\ddot{\gamma}_{TM}(t)||$ via $||\ddot{\gamma}_{M}(t)||$ with respect to $\kappa (\partial TS)$ on the basis of Euler-Lagrange, with idea being that if boundary of $S$ starts off more curved than geodesic then perhaps after $T$ same relationship holds. The main difficulty is that E-L solution is not very friendly.

Comment: What did you try? Why do you think positivity of curvature is relevant here? Do you know how to compute the Riemannian connection of $M\subset R^n$?

Comment: Without curvature positivity you can cook up a counter-example to this statement: M is flat everywhere except for a low ridge, S covers that ridge. A geodesic in S runs over this low ridge and remains in S. T stretches the ridge upwards a lot and geodesic is forced to go around leaving S.

Comment: I also tried analyzing $||\ddot{\gamma}_{TM}(t)||$ via $||\ddot{\gamma}_{M}(t)||$ with respect to $\kappa(\partial TS)$ on the basis of Euler-Lagrange, with idea being that if boundary of S starts off more curved than geodesic then perhaps after T same relationship holds. The main difficulty is that E-L solution is not very friendly.

Comment: Try using Jacobi fields.